# What is the right Chinese translation of the technical term 'Data Feed'?

Tags: translation

In most dictionaries, 'feed' is translated to '飼料' (Food for livestocks).

However if the word 'feed' is used in a computer technology context as to mean ['data feed'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_feed), what is the right Chinese translation?

**Edit:**

My ideal translation is to be able to convey an imagery of a continuous flow of data to the user's end.

It is because the word 'feed' is used to describe a UI element on a website which supports an 'endless scroll' feature.

Comment: Does web feed work for you? If so you can use: 消息来源. There’s also a transliteration of Data Feed: 戴特飞 but it doesn’t seem to be used universally.

Comment: I am looking forward to a translation that can convey the dynamism of the data flow. I have added more details to my question. Thanks very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

**馈送**

*[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E9%A6%88%E9%80%81)*

> to feed (a signal to a device, paper to a printer etc)

It also happens to be an alternative name for *[web feed](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%B6%88%E6%81%AF%E4%BE%86%E6%BA%90)*.

Answer (score 3):

Data is 數據.

Data feed is translated as 數據饋送  (Cantonese call it *數據傳送*)

We call data transmitting via satellite "satellite feed" (衛星饋電) (*衛星傳訊* in Cantonese)

Comment: Data normally translated to 数据(SC)/資料(TC).

Answer (score 1):

> My ideal translation is to be able to convey an imagery of a
>   continuous flow of data to the user's end.

Go with the flow, 流！Don't get hung up on **feed** , flow bro, stream sis!

来自....辅助.....数据..源.......得.....增量......数据..流。
from auxiliary data source get incremental data flow
Incremental data feed from secondary data sources.

> 数据流（data
>   stream）最初是通信领域使用的概念，代表传输中所使用的信息的数字编码信号序列。然而，我们所提到的数据流概念与此不同。这个概念最初在1998年由Henzinger在文献87中提出，他将数据流定义为“只能以事先规定好的顺序被读取一次的数据的一个序列”。

Answer (score 0):

Feed is 餵, 哺, 飼, 供, 給, 送, 進, 注, 入, 輸.

Data feed might be translated as 注入資料, 注入數據. But by its nature it is like broadcasting on the web. We could call it 資料轉播, 網上轉播, 數據轉播, or use 廣播 instead of 轉播 alternatively.

It is better to translate according to the context to make audience understand.

Answer (score 0):

I just done some search about the translation of "data feed" and...

[Microsoft Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language) suggests 数据馈送 for SC, and 資料摘要 for TC.

[Facebook Ads](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1013894008673621) suggests 数据信息库 for SC, and 資料摘要 for TC.

[Amazon AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/data-feed.html) suggests 数据源 for SC, no TC version.